# Unresolved externals on linking yaml-cpp against my project

Tags: c++, linker, yaml, yaml-cpp

When I try to link my project against yaml-cpp library, I get unresolved externals

> Error 1680    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class YAML::Node
>   __cdecl YAML::LoadFile(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)"
>   (?LoadFile@YAML@@YA?AVNode@1@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)

I built the lib using CMake and then building the project 'ALL BUILD'

The code is very simple:

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    YAML::LoadFile("config.yaml");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your linking command look like?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2013 so it gets a little big

Comment: You should paste it here anyways.

Comment: I have the same problem using Cmake files in linux